# How would we go about creating an animation of a sprite that moves from point to point?

Tags: java, animation, sprite, paintcomponent, drawimage

I'm using drawImage (paintComponent) etc to render everything. I'm wondering how I would go about having a sprite move from point A to B and actually show the movement to that point (animation).

Thanks!

Comment: You need some kind of trigger that updates the position from where it is to where you want it to be and the repaint the component, ensuring that you are using the current coordinates to paint the sprite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on the framework you are using, at the very basic level, you will need some kind of trigger which allows you to periodically update the position of the sprite with some kind of delta

In Swing, the simplest approach would be to use a `javax.swing.Timer` which allows you to fire an event at regular intervals, but which are triggered within the Event Dispatching Thread, reducing possible thread contamination and dirty paints

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SimpleSprite {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleSprite();
    }

    public SimpleSprite() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new AnimationPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class AnimationPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage dalek;
        private Point dalekPoint;
        private int deltaX = 1;

        public AnimationPane() {
            dalekPoint = new Point();
            try {
                dalek = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/dalek.png"));
                dalekPoint.y = (200 - dalek.getHeight()) / 2;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (dalekPoint.x + dalek.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                        dalekPoint.x = getWidth() - dalek.getWidth();
                        deltaX *= -1;
                    } else if (dalekPoint.x < 0) {
                        dalekPoint.x = 0;
                        deltaX *= -1;
                    } else {
                        dalekPoint.x += deltaX;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(dalek, dalekPoint.x, dalekPoint.y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Take a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer to render UI. For example:

```
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        int delay = 400; //milliseconds
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                // calculate x, y
                //drawImage
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
```